# Adding conditional IE css in NopCommerce head

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I've being trying to add a conditional CSS specific to IE 9 and lower, to NopCommerce head. However when I use the example NopCommerce provides, it removes the original style.
Here are the two CSS files I want to separate in my code.

```
@{
Html.AppendCssFileParts("~/Themes/website/Content/InternetExplorerStyle.css");
Html.AppendCssFileParts("~/Themes/website/Content/Style.css");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look how it's done in the Themes/DefaultClean/Views/Shared/Head.cshtml view. It should look like this:

```
//add browser specific CSS files
var browser = Request.Browser;
if (browser.Browser == "IE" && browser.MajorVersion <= 9)
{
    Html.AppendCssFileParts("~/Themes/website/Content/InternetExplorerStyle.css");
}
```